# Understanding difficulties on pthread

Tags: c, pthreads

I am trying to understand pthreads and I am compiling programs I find online.

[Here is a simple one](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/samples/hello.c).

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define NUM_THREADS 5

void *PrintHello(void *threadid)
{
   long tid;
   tid = (long)threadid;
   printf("Hello World! It's me, thread #%ld!\n", tid);
   pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];
   int rc;
   long t;
   for(t=0;t<NUM_THREADS;t++){
     printf("In main: creating thread %ld\n", t);
     rc = pthread_create(&threads[t], NULL, PrintHello, (void *)t);
     if (rc){
       printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is %d\n", rc);
       exit(-1);
       }
     }

   /* Last thing that main() should do */
   pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

So I cannot understand the syntax of the PrintHello function.

1)The "***PrintHello**" function name is something like o pointer(because of the star symbol)?

2)The **function's parameter** is a pointer with no type? So... not even a pointer?

3)How can we **cast a void type** of variable into a long?

Are we not able to build a simpler function and pass it in the thread?

4)At last in main, at pthread function, what does the **(void *)t** parameter means? :O

Thanks a lot guys!

Comment: You *do* know how pointers are declared? You *do* know about the generic pointer `void *`? Now look again at the `PrintHello` function declaration. And if you *don't* know about the generic pointer, now is the time to go to your favorite search engine and do some searching.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1)The "*PrintHello" function name is something like a pointer(because
>   of the star symbol)?

It's function, returning pointer to void. i.e. `void *`.

> 2)The function's parameter is a pointer with no type? So... not even a
>   pointer?

That's correct. The thread function *does* a take void pointer.

> 3)How can we cast a void type of variable into a long?

It's a conversion from pointer type to an integer type. This conversion is implementation-defined and potentially *undefined.* This will work on most implementations today but by no means fully portable.

> 4) Are we not able to build a simpler function and pass it in the
>   thread?

No. Because the [pthread_create()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html) function specifically expects a function pointer that takes a `void*` argument and returns `void*`. So you can't pass a different function.

> 5) At last in main, at pthread function, what does the (void *)t
>   parameter means?

This is integer to pointer conversion. The same comments in (3) applies here.

Answer (score 2):

`PrintHello()` is a *function* accepting a `void*` argument and returning a `void*` value.

If doubts persist, read [Kernighan and Ritchie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language) to learn C programming.

Answer (score 1):

You should study a litle bit of C language before deeping into parallelism. That way your study will be a lot easier:
A `void pointer` is a general purpose pointer. Check [this](http://www.c4learn.com/c-programming/c-void-pointers/) tutorial on `void` pointers.

Answer (score 1):

> **1:** Thread functions need to have a `void*` return type as a `void` pointer can be used to point to any piece of data in memory.
>
> **2:** Yes that's correct.
>
> **3:** This is a conversion from a `pointer` to an `int`.
>
> **4:** This is a `int` to `pointer` conversion.

You should read some basic tutorials on threads and read some books on C.